# Why isn't template argument deduction working?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, assign, template-argument-deduction

The following toy program converts a type of music to a corresponding color. It compiles and executes just fine--conversion of `COUNTRY` fails, as expected, and the `conversion()` function returns the default, `WHITE`. However, if I remove the template arguments, `<MUSIC, COLOR>`, template argument deduction does not recognize what types to use. How can I get deduction to work?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/assign.hpp"

template<typename Key, typename T>
T convert(const Key &k, const T &d, const std::map<Key, T> &m) {
    typename std::map<Key, T>::const_iterator it = m.find(k);
    return it == m.end() ? d : it->second;
}

enum MUSIC { ROCK, RAP, EDM, COUNTRY };
enum COLOR { RED, BLUE, ORANGE, WHITE };

int main()
{
    COLOR c = convert<MUSIC, COLOR>(COUNTRY, WHITE,
        boost::assign::map_list_of (RAP, RED) (EDM, BLUE) (ROCK, RED));
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add a template argument for the map type as well?

Comment: template<template<typename, typename> Map, typename Key, typename Value> > ... as per @jxh's suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boost::assign::map_list_of` probably isn't of type `map<K,V>`, but rather some type convertible to it.

The compiler is trying to deduce the type from both the first 2 arguments, and the last 1.  The last 1 makes no sense, so it gives up.

We can block deduction on the last argument as follows:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<class T>using block_deduction=type_t<tag<T>>;

template<typename Key, typename T>
T convert(const Key &k, const T &d, const block_deduction<std::map<Key, T>> &m) {
  typename std::map<Key, T>::const_iterator it = m.find(k);
  return it == m.end() ? d : it->second;
}
```

and bob should be your uncle.

In C++03:

```
template<class T>struct no_deduction{typedef T type;};

template<typename Key, typename T>
T convert(const Key &k, const T &d, const typename no_deduction<std::map<Key, T>>::type &m) {
  typename std::map<Key, T>::const_iterator it = m.find(k);
  return it == m.end() ? d : it->second;
}
```

which is logically equivalent, but much uglier.

Comment: Indeed it is an `assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<...>>`.

Comment: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49ea79b0be98705c) says: `'boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::pair<MUSIC, COLOR> >' is not derived from 'const std::map<Key, T>'
         boost::assign::map_list_of (RAP, RED) (EDM, BLUE) (ROCK, RED));`

Comment: @Barry aka, the reason why `auto` was invented.

Comment: @Yakk Oh of course. Just throwing out confirmation for your first sentence (as if you needed it)

Comment: @Yakk @NathanOliver Oh, forgot to say that I want a C++03 solution, so `auto` and an initializer list is out.

Comment: @Yakk You say, "The last 1 makes no sense, so it gives up," but all I have to do to make it work is provide the first two types, i.e., `<MUSIC, COLOR>`. Either way, I haven't provided the mysterious, third type. That's why I thought it had nothing to do with it. How does providing those first two types enable argument deduction for the third type?

Comment: @user4438540 template functions try to deduce their template args from the non-template args.  It gives no precedence to one set of args over another.  If the deduction gives matches everywhere, it works.  If it fails *anywhere* (before conversion to anything except base), it fails.  There is no way to match `std::map<MUSIC, COLOR>` on the 3rd non-template arg, so it fails.  If you provide the template args, no deduction is needed, none is done, and conversion occurs.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks! I had just wrestled your first, C+11 solution into a C++03 solution on my own, but yours is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

As [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31462647/4342498) `boost::assign::map_list_of` is not `std::map` but it is convertible to one.  If don't wan't to change your function you can change how you create the map.  With C++ we now have [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which can be used to construct an object.  Using an initializer list we can change

```
COLOR c = convert<MUSIC, COLOR>(COUNTRY, WHITE,
    boost::assign::map_list_of (RAP, RED) (EDM, BLUE) (ROCK, RED));
```

To

```
COLOR c = convert(COUNTRY, WHITE, {{RAP, RED},{EDM, BLUE},{ROCK, RED}});
```

Which will give use the same result and allow template type deduction to work.

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2424bdb90650932)